# If my wife is allowed to enter France with me, can she travel alone to France to join me?

Tags: customs-and-immigration, family

According to the current regulations, I (Polish citizen living in France) am allowed to travel from Israel to France together with my wife (Israeli citizen). To quote the relevant passage from the [ministerial webpage](https://www.diplomatie.gouv.fr/en/coming-to-france/coronavirus-advice-for-foreign-nationals-in-france/):

> If you are arriving from another country, you can only enter France if
> your journey meets one of the following criteria for exceptions:
>
> (...)
>
> 2.If you are a European Union citizen or a national of Andorra, the Holy
> See, Iceland, Liechtenstein, Monaco, Norway, San Marino, Switzerland
> or the United Kingdom, and your main residence is in France or you are
> crossing France to reach your country of nationality or residence (you
> may be accompanied by your spouse and children);

This phrasing strikes unusual since nowhere else do the regulations say that my wife is allowed to cross the border, it's only that I'm allowed to cross the border with her. I'm confused as to how such regulations are interpreted. Currently, I am in France and my wife is in Israel. Is she allowed to travel to join me? It would seem utterly illogical if she couldn't, but if the regulations are read literally that's exactly what they say.

Comment: Where is your wife's main residence?

Comment: If the next applies to your wife, then yes. **If you hold a valid French or European residence permit or long-stay visa and your main residence is in France or you are crossing France to reach your residence in the European space;** An article 10/20 card allows a holder to **join** the EU spouse.

Comment: It might be a translation problem, the French version is a lot more ambiguous. My guess is that this is actually intended to cover your wife. You can see that the list of exceptions is pretty extensive and mostly aimed at discouraging tourism and frivolous visits, not family or work-related trips.

Answer (score 2):

> If my wife is allowed to enter France with me [EEA state national], can she travel alone to France to join me?

Yes according to https://www.iatatravelcentre.com/world.php -> France

> Published 09.09.2020
>
> 1. Passengers are not allowed to enter.
>
> - This does not apply to:
> - nationals of France, if not arriving from French Guiana or Mayotte, and their spouses and children;
> - British nationals and nationals of Andorra, Monaco, San Marino, Switzerland, Vatican City (Holy See) and an **EEA Member State if not
>   arriving from French Guiana or Mayotte**; and **their spouses and children**

As recommended for many covid questions, it doesn't hurt to try to confirm with your airlines and embassies.